# Adding three or more matrices in one command

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, vectorization, binary-operators

For example, in Octave I can do the following:

```
A = randn(2);
B = randn(2);
C = randn(2);
plus(A, B, C)
```

This does not work in MATLAB however, because the plus function in MATLAB only allows two input arguments.

For context, I have a cell array full of large, sparse matrices and I need to add all of them together. I am looking for an efficient way to do this. For example, in Octave I would do the following:

```
D = {A, B, C};
plus(D{:})
```

But this doesn't work in MATLAB for the reason explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all matrices inside the cell array have the same size then you can [concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) each of them in a separate slice of a 3D array and then [sum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) along the 3rd dimension i.e.

```
sum(cat(3,D{:}),3)
```

This is not valid if your cell array is a combination of scalars and matrices, or if you're doing implicit expansion with `plus`.

---

If the cell array has combination of matrices of different size then just use a loop. Loops have been significantly improved in the newer versions of MATLAB.

```
req = 0;
for k = 1:numel(D)
    req = req + D{k}; %or bsxfun(@plus, req, D{k}) for < R2016b
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I came across this answer in another forum and it works for dense matrices, but not sparse matrices---you can't concatenate sparse matrices in a dimension > 2. I'll use a loop if I have to but I tend to try to avoid them unless absolutely necessary!